# Using NumberPicker to change TextView on a different activity [android]

Tags: java, android, textview, numberpicker

I'm trying to change a textview value on one activity by using a numberpicker on the previous activity. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the relevant part of my Java from activity1

```
public class activity_game extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        final NumberPicker fizzNumberPkr = (NumberPicker)findViewById(fizzNumberPicker);
        fizzNumberPkr.setValue(3);
        fizzNumberPkr.setMinValue(1);
        fizzNumberPkr.setMaxValue(20);
        fizzNumberPkr.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
        final NumberPicker buzzNumberPkr = (NumberPicker)findViewById(buzzNumberPicker);
        buzzNumberPkr.setValue(5);
        buzzNumberPkr.setMinValue(1);
        buzzNumberPkr.setMaxValue(20);
        buzzNumberPkr.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);

    }

    public void toActivityPlay (View view) {
        Intent toActivityPlay = new Intent(this, activity_play.class);
        toActivityPlay.putExtra("fizzNumber", fizzNumber);
        toActivityPlay.putExtra("buzzNumber", buzzNumber);
        startActivity(toActivityPlay);
    }
```

And my relevant java from activity2

```
public class activity_play extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);

        TextView fizzNumberText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.fizzNumber);
        fizzNumberText.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("fizzNumber"));

        if(getIntent().hasExtra("fizzNumber")) {
            fizzNumber = getIntent().getIntArrayExtra();
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error: Fizz number not found");
        }
```

If there's any relevant code that I may not have posted please let me know and i'll edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas come to me now to communicate two activities.. 
You can create a method setValuePicker()/getValueFromPicker() in the first Activity, and call getValue() in the other activity.

```
public void setValuePicker(Parameter value){
    number = value;
}

public Parameter getValuePicker(){
    return value;
}
```

If you variable have been set global only need implement getValue() method.

If you someday want use fragments need implement callback.

---

***EDIT:***

Using your code is something like this:
- FirstActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int number;
    public static final String FIZZ_TAG = "fizz_numer";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final NumberPicker picker = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);
        picker.setMinValue(0);
        picker.setMaxValue(10);
        picker.setValue(5);
        picker.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                number = picker.getValue();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main2Activity.class)
                        .putExtra(FIZZ_TAG,number);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

- Second Activity need be something like this.
  .
  .
  .
  .

  ```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    int s = getIntent().getIntExtra(MainActivity.FIZZ_TAG,0);

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_test);
    textView.setText(String.format("%s = %d","number ",s));

  }
  ```